# Is choosing to use "which" in this sentence wrong?

Tags: pronouns

In an adjective clause with relative pronouns exercise,

> However, in the acknowledgment,_________ the author has more room,
>   everyone from reference librarians  to proofreaders is thanked.

I chose *which*. The professor said it was wrong and should have been *where*. Now I know that it is more correct to use *where* since we are metaphorically talking about a place, which is the acknowledgment, that the author has more room in. But I don't feel that it is completely incorrect to have chosen *which*. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are wrong. Perhaps you are thinking about "in which", which would be usable: "in which the author has more room [to write]". Note that "in which", like "where", refers to a place.

Comment: Yeah, but why is it not right to choose which in that sentence?

Comment: I'm not a grammar expert, but "which" is used when there is some sort of choice: "Which ice cream would you like?", or where the clause indicates  a conditional: "which would be usable". Best I can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: Where the relative word is adjunct of place, as it is here, the logical choice is "where" which here means "in which". We understand the relative clause as "the author has more room __", where gap is co-referenced to "where" which is anaphoric to the locative preposition phrase "in the acknowledgment".

Comment: @BillJ But I still don't understand why using which is incorrect.

Comment: It's because the antecedent of the relative word is the preposition phrase "in the acknowledgment", and only "where" can represent that locative meaning. "Which" when used alone would typically refer to some thing, or perhaps a clause as in, for example, "It costs a great deal of money, which I can't afford at the moment"; "Ed was late arriving, which caused a few problems".